# Java Regular Expression not evaluating

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that is changes frequently, in the form of :

```
*** START OF THIS PROJECT FILENAME ***
```

Where FILENAME can be multiple words in different instances. I tried running the regex :

```
Pattern.matches("\\*\\*\\* START OF THIS PROJECT ", line);
```

where line is equal to one such strings. 
I also tried using the Matcher, where beginningOfFilePatter is also set to the same regex pattern above:

```
Matcher beginFileAccelerator;
beginFileAccelerator = beginningOfFilePattern.matcher(line);
if (beginFileAccelerator.find() 
//Do Something
```

Ive exhuastively tried at least 30 different combinations of regex, and I simply can't find the solution. If anyone could lend me an eye I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

[`Pattern.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-) tries to match the **entire** string against the pattern, because under the covers it uses [`Matcher#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--), which says:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

In your case, that will fail at the end, because the input doesn't end with `"PROJECT "`. It has more after that.

To allow anything at the end, add `.*`:

```
Pattern.matches("\\*\\*\\* START OF THIS PROJECT .*", line)
// Here -----------------------------------------^
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/i2Kizf)